# How to delete a dynamically generated form based on the click of the delete button with respect to its ID in vuejs2

Tags: vuejs2, quasar

I am creating an application using Quasar and  VueJS. I am able to generate a dynamic form on click of the add button, but not able to delete any of the newly generated form based on the click of the delete button.Find the code below:

```
<template>              
<div v-for="h in htmlList">
     <div v-for="r in h" >
         <div v-html="r" v-on:click="useRemoveFromProject(1)" v-bind:id="r.id">
         </div>
    </div>               
</div>
</template>

<script>
/*
 * Root component
 */
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {
  name: 'q-app',
  data () {
    return {
      flag: 0,
      htmlList: [],
      select: 'fb',
      select1: 'fb1',
      multipleSelect: ['goog', 'twtr'],
      usersInProject: [],
      selectOptions: [
        {
          label: 'Google',
          value: 'goog'
        },
        {
          label: 'Select',
          value: 'fb'
        },
        {
          label: 'Twitter',
          value: 'twtr'
        },
        {
          label: 'Apple Inc.',
          value: 'appl'
        },
        {
          label: 'Oracle',
          value: 'ora'
        }
      ],
      selectOptions1: [
        {
          label: 'Integer',
          value: 'goog1'
        },
        {
          label: 'Float',
          value: 'fb1'
        },
        {
          label: 'String',
          value: 'twtr1'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    useRemoveFromProject: function (id) {
      console.log('hi....')
      Vue.delete(this.htmlList, id)
    },
    identifyMe: function (event) {
      alert('hi - ' + event.target.id)
    },
    process: function () {
      this.flag += 1
      let temp = []
      temp.push('<div class="card" id="a_' + this.flag + '"> <div class="card-content content-center "> <large id="l4">Expression LHS:</large> <input><br> <large id="l5">Operators:</large> <q-select type="radio" v-model="this.select" :options="this.selectOptions"></q-select><br><large id="l4">Expression RHS:</large> <input><br><large id="l5">Data type:</large> <q-select type="radio" v-model="select1" :options="selectOptions1"></q-select><br></div><button class="cordova-hide circular red " style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-right:30px;"  v-on:click="userRemoveFromProject(i)"><i>delete</i></button><input value="click" type="button"> </div>')
      let ids = ['a_' + this.flag]
      console.log(ids)
      this.htmlList.push(temp)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is the version of vue you are using?

Comment: `useRemoveFromProject(1)` so the key is always 1? Are you sure about it? (for me it means it will only delete the second element if exists). Maybe look at the index of the current element?

Answer (score 0):

After looking to your code i noticed that you have some errors:

- Call function `useRemoveFromProject` without the 'r' of 'user'
- Call `userRemoveFromProject` when clicking on the element and not only the delete button
- Call `userRemoveFromProject(i)` with a 'i' variable, but what is 'i' ?
- Why using a double `v-for`? The first level is enough.

I propose to you a working example on a fiddle. Please let me know if it's useful for you (and mark it as resolve if it's the case).

EDIT: for Vue.js 2 https://jsfiddle.net/86216oko/